# Can I stub a function that is three levels deep from the function I am testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have this scenario and I am trying to write the unitTest for it

```
    const processAllItems = (listOfItems) => {
      //some processing and then
      let itemListProcessed = [];
      let itemProcessed;
      listOfItems.forEach(item => {
        itemProcessed = processItem(item)
        itemListProcessed.push(itemProcessed);
      })
      return itemListProcessed;
    }


    const processItem = (item) => {
      //Do some processing and then
      let validItem = isItemValid(item);
      if(validItem) {
        // do some processing
      } 
      else {
        //do something else
      }
    }


    const isItemValid = (item) => {
      if(item)  return true
      else  return false
      }
    }
```

I am writing unit tests for it. I want to test the high level method (processAllItems()). Inside this method processItem() is called, and inside processItem() method is another method isItemValid(). How can I stub the isValidItem() method to always return true without stubbing the processItem() method.
I tried this but it didn't work:

```
        sandbox.stub(mainService, 'isItemValid').callsFake(() => {
        console.log("stub is triggered")
        return true;
    });
```

Thank you in advance, any help would be appreciated. I am using mocha/sinon

and this is how my code looks like:

```
// Inside this file are all three methods described on the post
const mainService = require('pathToFile'); 
describe.only('Check processAllItems', async function() {
    let sandbox;
    before(async function() {
        sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    })

    after(async function () {
        sandbox.restore();
    })

    it.only('should process sale', async function() {
        sandbox.stub(mainService, 'isValidItem').callsFake(() => {
            return false;
        });

        let resutls = await mainService.processAllItems(record);
    })   
})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work? Maybe share the full test-case code for us to get a better overview.

Comment: the stub is not triggered at all. I added a console.log() before returning TRUE and it doesn't print the message at all

Comment: I see.. How are you calling `processAllItems` in the test?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: `isValidItem` is not called on the `mainService` object. `processAllItems` has a direct reference to the function `processItem`, which has a direct reference to `isItemValid`. To proceed you could refactor to have these functions in a class, which you'll then instantiate and then use the stubbing on the instance object.

Answer (score 0):

I use [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) package module to stub `isItemValid` function. E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
const processAllItems = (listOfItems) => {
  let itemListProcessed = [];
  let itemProcessed;
  listOfItems.forEach((item) => {
    itemProcessed = processItem(item);
    itemListProcessed.push(itemProcessed);
  });
  return itemListProcessed;
};

const processItem = (item) => {
  let validItem = isItemValid(item);
  if (validItem) {
  } else {
  }
  return validItem;
};

const isItemValid = (item) => {
  if (item) return true;
  return false;
};

module.exports = { processAllItems };
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const rewire = require('rewire');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('Check processAllItems', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mod = rewire('./');
    const isItemValidStub = sinon.stub().returns(true);
    mod.__set__('isItemValid', isItemValidStub);
    const listOfItems = [0, 1];
    const actual = mod.processAllItems(listOfItems);
    expect(actual).to.be.eql([true, true]);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(isItemValidStub.firstCall, 0);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(isItemValidStub.secondCall, 1);
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
  Check processAllItems
    ✓ should pass (696ms)


  1 passing (704ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |      80 |       25 |      75 |   85.71 |                   
 index.js |      80 |       25 |      75 |   85.71 | 20,21             
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/60857745